# Converting 32-bit and 64-bit numbers to IEEE 754 binary in C

Tags: c, ieee-754

I am currently working on a program where I need to have this kind of output:

[image: Example using -3.14 as an example input]

I have to output the binary in IEEE 754 of 64 and 32-bit numbers in C.

I already have the double and single floating point approximation, but I'm having trouble finding out how to output the binary of these in IEEE 754 notation, and color code them as well. Any thoughts/solutions on how to do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: The simplest one would be to make a pointer to the float num and then read byte by byte and convert that to binary.

Comment: If you have a 64-bit integer type, you don't even need the byte by byte breakdown

Comment: For color coding console output, look at conio.h if you are on windows; ncurses if you are on linux

Comment: Would be better to use windows.h than conio.h. Get a handle for the io, e.g. `HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);` Then use `SetConsoleAttribute()` see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for details

Comment: Your issue lies in this statement `((u >> i) & i )`, which should instead be `((u >> i) & 1)` =)

Comment: Thank you sir! You're algorithm works.  The only other issue I'm having is  my program won't exit the while loop when I enter an "e", do you see anything that may be causing it not to exit? Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: Aha! It exits now, instead of using "strcmp" I used "strncmp" and compared only the first character of each array. Works great! Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not guarantee the correct answer if the underlying machine is something esoteric, however:

```
float f = 3.14;
uint32_t u;
memcpy(&u, &f, sizeof u);
for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--)
  putchar('0' + ((u >> i) & 1));
```

Comment: As an aside, I would be very interested to see a way that does not involve UB. It is sad that this being the most typical method is also the least portable...

Comment: `memcpy(&i, &f, sizeof(i))` does the job without invoking UB.

Comment: Hmm yes you might be right, ill edit it to reflect that. It still does not guarantee that the bits you read out will be in anyway useful however.

Comment: Also, aaaah: `[u.i & (1<<i)]` yields a huge index, and if you shift 1 by 31 or more you have UB. Surely you meant `[(u.i >> i) & 1]`?

Comment: Good catch, indeed what I meant.

Comment: The `putc` expression would be simpler and more efficient written this way: `putchar('0' + ((u >> i) & 1));`.  You can also get rid of `memcpy` with a simple cast: `u = *(uint32_t)&f;`

Comment: @chqrlie I agree with the first point, however your second would I believe invoke UB, see the discussion and edits.

Comment: Also it could be made even more efficient by shifting u instead of using a counter, however that I wont do to risk losing clarity for the OP.

Comment: @Segmented: I posted an answer which does not (I think) involve UB. Check it out.

Comment: I'm running into all kinds of errors when i try to implement this. I'm using linux gcc compiler and its not liking when i declare variables in for loops and when i use uint32_t. Sorry, I'm not good with programming.

Comment: @DaveH. Either compile it with the flag `-std=c99` or declare all your variables at the top of your function. You will also need to `#include <stdint.h>` for uint32_t. Hope that helps.

Comment: Okay, so it runs but how would i  just directly output it? putchar() seems to be tacking on to the single-precision floating point approximation number that i output right before it, and i used an endline after it so that shouldn't be happening. It also outputs random characters like & and just a bunch of zeros and no ones. Thanks for your help

Comment: @DaveH. putchar prints a single character to stdout, in this case a '0' or '1'. This snippet should output the underlying binary representation of the float. Perhaps you need a newline after whatever else you are printing first (and before whatever you are printing thereafter)?

Comment: So when I use the function you provided, and use 3.14 as my input i recieve this output:   00048@0000041B00125<:88036440010. I implemented the function exactly as you did except i declared my variables at the top

Comment: Also, i put my latest code in my question. Take a look at it and if you see anything I'm doing wrong let me know. Just as a reminder I'm using Linux gcc to compile this program. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to take the opportunity to refresh my memory of the IEE-754 floating-point standard. Below is a mashup I made for displaying a string in its single-precision floating point number representation, though it is easily modified for the double-precision format.

The code won't work with +Inf, -Inf, NaN, trailing-zero, fractionless and leftout-zero (`.fraction` instead of `0.fraction` or `integer.` instead of `integer.0`) numbers, it's just supposed to give the general idea of how to do what you want to do in a portable and well-defined (and highly entertaining) way.

```
#define EXPLEN 8 /* Fraction length for single-precision */
#define SIGNIFLEN 23 /* Significand length for single-precision */
#define EXPBIAS 0x7F /* Exponent bias for single-precision */
#define BITLEN (1 + EXPLEN + SIGNIFLEN)

BOOL strToFloat(char *floatStr, char *outBits, size_t outBitsLen){
    unsigned long int floatStrLength = strlen(floatStr), intPart, fracPart, intPartHighestBit = 1, fracPartLength,
        fracPartPowTen = 1, temp;
    char roundBit, stickyBit, expPart = 0;
    int i;

    /* Get sign */
    if (floatStr[0] == '-'){
        floatStr++;
        outBits[0] = '1';
    } else {
        if (floatStr[0] == '+')
            floatStr++;
        outBits[0] = '0';
    }

    if (sscanf(floatStr, "%lu.%lu", &intPart, &fracPart) == EOF ||
        outBitsLen < BITLEN + 1)
        return FALSE; /* Failure */

    /* Get integer part */
    temp = intPart;
    while (temp >>= 1)
        intPartHighestBit <<= 1;

    for (i = EXPLEN + 1; i < BITLEN && (intPartHighestBit >>= 1); i++, expPart++)
        outBits[i] = !!(intPart & intPartHighestBit) + '0';

    /* Get fraction part */
    fracPartLength = strlen(strchr(floatStr, '.'));
    while (--fracPartLength)
        fracPartPowTen *= 10;

    if (!intPart && i == EXPLEN + 1)
        if (fracPart > 0){
            i--;
            expPart--;
        } else
            expPart = -EXPBIAS;

    for (; i < BITLEN; fracPart = (fracPart << 1) % fracPartPowTen){
        outBits[i] = !!((fracPart << 1) - (fracPart << 1) % fracPartPowTen) + '0';

        if (outBits[i] == '0' && i == EXPLEN) /* Start writing only after first set bit is reached if number <1 */
            expPart--;
        else
            i++;
    }

    /* Get exponent part */
    for (i = EXPLEN, expPart += EXPBIAS; i > 0; i--, expPart >>= 1)
        outBits[i] = (unsigned char)expPart % 2 + '0';

    /* Round fraction part (to-nearest mode) */
    if ((fracPart << 1) - (fracPart << 1) % fracPartPowTen){ /* Guard bit set, rounding needed */
        fracPart = (fracPart << 1) % fracPartPowTen;

        roundBit = !!((fracPart << 1) - (fracPart << 1) % fracPartPowTen);
        fracPart = (fracPart << 1) % fracPartPowTen;

        stickyBit = !!((fracPart << 1) - (fracPart << 1) % fracPartPowTen);

        if (roundBit || stickyBit || outBits[BITLEN - 1] == '0'){ /* Round up, add 1 to mantissa (and to exponent
                    if mantissa overflows)*/
            for (i = BITLEN - 1; outBits[i] == '1' && i > 0; i--)
                outBits[i] = '0';
            outBits[i] = '1';
        }
    }

    outBits[BITLEN] = '\0';

    return TRUE; /* Success */
}
```

Example usage:

```
char *str = "-3.14",
    *outFloat = malloc(BITLEN + 1);

if (outFloat && strToFloat(str, outFloat, BITLEN + 1))
    printf("%s", outFloat);
```

outputs

```
11000000010010001111010111000011
```

**UPDATE**: did my best to

- remove magic numbers so it's easier to change this to use the double-precision format;
- fix (I think) the rounding overflows;
- fix zeroes issues;
- refactor the code for setting the sign bit; and I also fiddled with some types, both per @Segmented's request in the comments.

Well, that was lots of fun! If you see any errors or space for improvement in this (rather hasty) code, please post it!

Comment: Ambitious! I would probably refactor that first line to use if statements since the potential side-effect isn't immediately obvious. Some of those variables should also be unsigned, I would recommend the uint*_t family as they guarantee the number of bits.

Comment: @Segmented: done, take a look. I didn't use the `uint*_t` types because I have a strong habit of making my code C89-compatible if it's not over-problematic to do so.